# Qt error: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: qt

[image]
I want to create a simple project in Qt Creator , but I can't run it.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLabel label("Hello, world");
    label.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is my .pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-08-03T16:29:59
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Hello
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h
```

I am a absolutely freshmen for qt and I just follow some course in the Internet,so I don't know what's wrong with it.My mac os : 10.12.3 . Qt Creator : 4.3.1 based on Qt 5.9.1 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Comment: show your .pro, please

Comment: Under Build: Clean , run  qMake, run

Comment: Thank you for answering my question,I have upload the .pro.

Comment: You can display the complete error message, in addition to the information of your OS, and the version of Qt you have installed.